# Comparing two lists to count how many times predictions match results

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have two columns. One is a prediction, one is the result. I want to count how many times the prediction matches the result (i.e. a correct prediction). The data is like so:

```
Col A     Col B
Bears     Cats
Dogs      Cats
Cats      Pumas
Turtles   Pumas
```

So the number I want to get to via a formula is `2`, since that's how many matches there were (`Cats`).

Comment: Your question isn't clear now, please clearly explain what do you mean by match (count of cats in column B??). Also please let us know what have you tried so far. Please don't answer in a comment, but edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will get the number of correct predictions from `Column B`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B5,A2:A5,0))))
```

This formula looks up the values in `Column B` and checks to see if they are in `Column A` using the `MATCH` function.

Note the double negative sign is used to transform a result of `True` into a value of `1` and a result of `False` into a value of `0`.